# How to manually call functions that come with some libraries

Tags: javascript

I have installed a lightbox plugin and i would like to resue some if its functionality for other parts of my application without having to recode a separate module since it would be kind of redundant, so is it possible to reuse/share some functions from a library like say from this one

http://www.notesfor.net/samples/jquery/notesforlightbox/js/nf.lightbox.js

My intention is this light box plug in already supports hotkeys for Next, Previous, Close etc...

Here is the situation... form the lightbox.js...
I want to reuse this particular function for another part of my application

```
(function($) {
$.fn.lightBox = function(settings) {
```

....
......
......
..... etc ...

```
    function _keyboard_action(objEvent) {
        // To ie
        if (objEvent == null) {
            keycode = event.keyCode;
            escapeKey = 27;
            // To Mozilla
        } else {
            keycode = objEvent.keyCode;
            escapeKey = objEvent.DOM_VK_ESCAPE;
        }
        // Get the key in lower case form
        key = String.fromCharCode(keycode).toLowerCase();
        // Verify the keys to close the ligthBox
        if ((key == settings.keyToClose) || (key == 'x') || (keycode == escapeKey)) {
            _finish();
        }
        // Verify the key to show the previous image
        if ((key == settings.keyToPrev) || (keycode == 37)) {
            // If we´re not showing the first image, call the previous
            if (settings.activeImage != 0) {
                settings.activeImage = settings.activeImage - 1;
                _set_image_to_view();
                _disable_keyboard_navigation();
            }
        }
        // Verify the key to show the next image
        if ((key == settings.keyToNext) || (keycode == 39)) {
            // If we´re not showing the last image, call the next
            if (settings.activeImage != (settings.imageArray.length - 1)) {
                settings.activeImage = settings.activeImage + 1;
                _set_image_to_view();
                _disable_keyboard_navigation();
            }
        }
    }
```

....
......
......
..... etc ...

```
};
```

})(jQuery);

but if i call : _keyboard_action(objEvent) from outside, i would get an error, so what is the correct syntax to do so?

Comment: I think, _keyboard_action is a private function of lightbox, so you can not access it. To make it reusable either you need to modify this implementation or you can copy this logic to make your own function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood from this post (and If I'm not misunderstood), you can simply use

```
<script src="NameOfJavascriptFile.js" type="text/javascript">
```

in your html `<head>` section and then call the functions like normal functions.

Comment: no that's not what i meant, that is just including the library which is no problem, the thing is how do i call the methods

Comment: Call the function in your code as you would call any other normal function in your script.

Comment: You have to put closing tag also `<script src="NameOfJavascriptFile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` unless it will not appear the script will not load. You can't use  `<script ...>` or `<script ... />` only.

Comment: not quite the answer... ok let me try to make it clearer again... please refer to my edited post above